# what is the easiest way to assign a function call to another with an extra argument

Tags: javascript

I have a function call like :

```
{
.
.
.
externals: (ctx, request, callback) => externalsHandler(ctx, request, callback, ['a', 'b'])
}
```

as you can see,  I'm calling a function inside externals and passing all of its arguments plus one array

I want to know if there is an easier way to do that.

one thing i found working is:

```
externals: (...args) => externalsHandler(...args, ['a', 'b'])
```

Is there any way to write this simpler?

Comment: The `(...args)` method is already in its simplest form and a lot better than the former method.

Comment: If it's possible to change the order of the arguments you can do something like `externals: externalsHandler.bind(['a', 'b'])`. AFAIK you can only bind the first arguments.

Comment: Depends on what you consider simpler. Could use a wrapper function. `const fn = (extraArg) => (...args) => externalsHandler(...args, extraArg);`    ...  `externals: fn(['a', 'b'])`

Comment: @jabaa yes i can change order but its not working can u post snippet as answer?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, you're given a list of arguments, which you would like to apply to a function. As mentioned above, you can use the spread syntax `(...)` or you can use the [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method like so

```
(...args) => externalsHandler.apply(null, args.concat(['a', 'b'])
```

Comment: apply needs a `thisArg`. If none needed still need a placeholder like null

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for pointing that out, I'd missed that.

Comment: Maybe not, but I find it cleaner

Comment: In fact, because it's cleaner, I would argue it's simpler also. It may be longer, but it's significantly faster to read, imo